# Shiny serverside suggestions according to user typing

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I would like to update the choices of a `pickerInput` according to what the user starts typing. Similar to what happens when you start typing with Google.

[image]

The suggestions have to be handled serverside.

Below is my code. The problem is that what the user is typing - if it's not an existing choice - is not sent to the server. Is there a way to send what the user types?

Maybe `pickerInput` is not the right approach? How else could I accomplish this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

suggest <- function(x) {
  # would in reality send whatever the user starts typing to an API that returns suggestions
  choices <- c("Some", "One", "Suggests", "This", "According", "To", "Input")
  choices[grep(x, choices, ignore.case = T)]
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(inputId = "id1",
              choices = c(),
              options = list(`live-search` = T))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    req(input$one)
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "id1", choices = suggest())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shiny::selectizeInput()` to achieve what you want:

```r
library(shiny)

# Generate arbitrarily thousands of choices which can only be rendered 
# serverside to avoid app slowdown:
k <- expand.grid(col1 = letters, col2 = letters, col3 = LETTERS)
choices <- with(k, paste0(col1, col2, col3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "selector", 
    label = "Selector", 
    choices = NULL
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "selector",
      choices = choices, 
      server = TRUE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>